# will the android old edition apk cache be used by the new edition apk

Tags: android, sqlite

my android apk will write some data into local database `SQLite`, and when I upgrade the apk to a new version, will the cached data be used by the new version.

If yes, I want to clean the cache because it will effect the behavior of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the new version will use the old cache.
If you want to clean it, just add a code in your new program where you delete all the relevant tables.
 Or you just can delete the database all together.

```
context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
```